# Ejabberd server keeps logging me off and back on constantly

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm building an iOS app, but the problem exists on all clients. iChat, Messages, Psi, etc. So because it exists on all clients I'm going to assume it's a server issue.

Has anyone ever experienced something like this? If so, what did you do to fix it? I'm sure it's some silly config setting or something but I simply can't figure this out. This is the only thing that looks like it might be related in ejabberd.log:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2012-09-05 12:07:12 ===
Mnesia(ejabberd@localhost): ** WARNING ** Mnesia is overloaded: {dump_log,
                                                             time_threshold}
```

Thanks in advance for any tips/pointers.

Comment: I should mention that I have no idea if that error (above) is even related to the issue though. It's disconnecting and reconnecting right now and even though I cleared out the ejabberd.log file... it contains nothing. So this issue doesn't seem to be logging anything. Grr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd_c2s.erl#L936 seems to have already been patched. The config variable is called resource_conflict and the value you want is setresource.

Answer (score 2):

The above warning is (probably) not related to the issue you are facing. These [mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html) [events](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html#id76510) usually happens when the transaction log needs to be dumped, but the previous transaction log dump hasn't finished yet.

Problem that you are facing needs to be debugged for which you can set `{log_level, 5}` inside `ejabberd.cfg`. This will enable debug logging for ejabberd. Then look into the logs to find any guesses on why this is happening for you. Also, come back and paste your log file details here, probably we will be able to help you further. I have never faced such non-sensical issues with ejabberd.

**Update after log file attachment:**

As Joe wrote below, this is indeed happening because of resource conflict. Two of your clients are trying to login with same resource value. But in an ideal world this shouldn't matter. Jabber servers SHOULD take care of this by appending or prepending custom value on top of resource value requested by the client.

For example, here is what gtalk (even facebook chat) servers will do:

```
SENT <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="set" id="1"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><resource>jaxl#resource</resource></bind></iq>
RCVD <iq id="1" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>jabberxmpplibrary@gmail.com/jaxl#resou27F46704</jid></bind></iq>
```

As you can see my client requested to bind with resource value `jaxl#resource` but gtalk server actually bound my session with resource value `jaxl#resou27F46704`. In short, this is not a bug in your client but a bug in ejabberd.

To fix this you can do two things:

1. Resource value is probably hardcoded somewhere in your client configuration. Simply remove that. A good client will automatically take care of this by generating a random resource value at it's end.
2. Patch ejabberd to behave how gtalk server does (as shown above). This is the relevant section inside [ejabberd_c2s.erl](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd_c2s.erl#L936) src which needs some tweaking. Also search for `Replaced by new connection` inside the c2s source file and you will understand what's going on.

Comment: Ah very good idea. I didn't know I could increase the log level. Here is the log file: http://pastebin.com/Jrva1UJJ I changed some of the basic info like hostname and usernames, but please let me know if passwords or any other private info is visible. I tried looking through that but dang it's long and seems like a lot of repeated info. I searched for "warning" and "error" and only error turned up 2 results (line 3480). Thanks for any tips too!!!! I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Abhinav! What I don't get however is why all of my clients do it. So it's not just something that I'm hardcoding in my client. Also, I just installed a test version of ejabberd (same version as this one which is running on linux) and it's fine (that was confusing... linux build has issue, osx build does not). Wouldn't they both use the same code base?

Comment: what clients are you using? what ejabberd versions have you tested this with? Can you link them here

Comment: iChat, Messages, Psi, my test app. http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/ 2.1.11 on both servers. CentOS 6.3 version was installed with the Linux 64bit installer. OSX Lion was installed with the 64bit osx installer.

Comment: `Messages --> Preferences --> Accounts --> Choose your account --> Chat Settings --> Location` (this defaults to "Use my computer name") , similarly you can see hardcoded values in other clients. As far as source code is concerned, it will behave the same everywhere since your are using one version i.e. 2.1.11 (I thought you have different versions of ejabberd installed).

Comment: Hmm, this is absolutely without question NOT what is causing ejabberd to log it's users off and on constantly. I can have one registered JID on the server and it will still do it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the "dueling resources" bug in your client.  You may have two copies of your client running simultaneously using the same resource, and doing faulty auto-reconnect logic.  When the second client logs in, the first client is booted offline with a conflict error.  The first client logs back in, causing a conflict error on the second client.  Loop.

Evidence for this is in your logfile, on line 3480:

```
D(<0.373.0>:ejabberd_c2s:1553) : Send XML on stream = 
  <<"<stream:error><conflict xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/>
       <text xml:lang='en' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'>
         Replaced by new connection
       </text>
     </stream:error>">>
```

Comment: Oh crazy. This is a known bug with ejabberd?

Comment: I guess I should have asked if it was known AND if there are any known fixes.

Comment: This is not a bug, you cannot have two clients connect with the same full JID at the same time.  They have to have different resources, and thus different full JID's.  That being said, your different clients would typically use different resources, such as /pidgin for Pidgin.  You should check what resources are specified in each of your clients.

Comment: This is not a server bug.  It is a client but that almost *every* client and client library has had over the years.

Comment: Interesting. So if a client tries to connect more than once it will log everyone off the server and back on? Sounds like a server bug to me. If handled properly it would seem to me that it would just log off the 1st instance of the same JID. Thanks for the info guys!

Comment: No.  If a user tries to log in with a different client using the same full JID (localpart@domain/resource), it will kick off the first client with the same full JID.  It has nothing to do with other users.